# Choosing Between Static Methods and Class Instances for a NetworkManager in Flutter

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, http, memory-management

I'm currently working on a Flutter application where I've implemented a `NetworkManager` class responsible for handling network requests. I've designed it as an abstract class with static methods, allowing me to use it directly without creating instances.

```dart
abstract class NetworkManager {
  static Future<void> postReq() async {
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

This approach provides a simple and direct way to use the network functionality throughout my application. However, I'm curious about the potential impact on memory usage and app performance.

**Considerations:**

- The application is relatively large, and I want to ensure optimal memory usage.
- I'm concerned about potential performance implications, especially during frequent network interactions.

**Question:**

- In terms of memory usage and app performance, what are the pros and cons of using static methods on an abstract class like I've done with `NetworkManager`?
- Would using instances of the class be a more memory-efficient and performant alternative, and are there specific scenarios where one approach might be preferred over the other?

I appreciate any insights, experiences, or best practices that the community can share regarding this design choice. My goal is to make an informed decision based on a combination of best practices and real-world experiences.

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of thinking that there's a set of "golden rules" for performance that if you just learn all of them and apply them blindly you'll always get the best performance. There aren't, or rather, there are billions and they all come with tons of caveats. If performance matters in a particular situation, set specific goals, implement in the most straightforward manner you can think of and then measure.

Comment: I acknowledge the complexity of performance optimization and the absence of universal rules. However, I believe seeking insights and experiences from the community is valuable. I'll certainly implement and measure, as you suggest, but if you have any specific advice or metrics you find effective, I would greatly appreciate it. Your input is invaluable as I navigate this design choice for my Flutter application.

Answer (score 0):

Any difference in memory usage should be negligible.  By having a singleton instance, you would need to allocate memory for a single object.  Big deal.

I'd expect that using instance methods probably would have a slight impact to performance since non-`static` method calls would need to go through virtual dispatch.  However, that performance impact also is likely to be negligible compared to other costs in your program (like, say, the cost of making a network request and waiting for the response).  Caring about the cost of virtual dispatch seems like a premature optimization.

Meanwhile, using `static` methods (which are equivalent to global functions but with a different scope) makes your code *significantly* harder to test.  If you have a single instance, then your tests can replace that instance with a mock so that your tests don't actually need to make network requests.  I don't think sacrificing easier testability is worth the trade-off.